# Разве безопасно хранить auth-токен пользователя в куках?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, авторизация, шифрование, пароль

Райан Бэйтс в своих RailsCastsPro как-то сказал: "на самом деле в куках небезопасно хранить просто id пользователя, так как он является легко угадываемым и даже очевидным. Вместо этого мы будем генерировать для каждого пользователя случайный auth-токен и уже его будет записывать в куку."
Но тут я подумал: пароль в базе данных в открытом виде мы не храним по той причине, что, если злоумышленник получит доступ к БД, то он сможет получить доступ к любому аккаунты, если пароли хранятся в незашифрованном виде. Тогда какой смысл в auth-токене? Если есть доступ к БД, в которой лежит auth-токен, то почему злоумышленник не может взять его для конкретного пользователя и поместить в куку у себя на ПК?
Лично я считаю, что нужно в куке хранить пароль пользователя (уже зашифрованную версию) в перемешку с id пользователя. Единственное, что такой подход будет довольно конкретно замедлять загрузку страницы. Как же быть?

Comment: Токен может иметь более короткий срок жизни чем пароль. После чего протухать, и его кража не позволит войти в систему. Также токен можно принудительно удалить на сервере, не меняя пароля, делая его бесполезным. С паролем так не сделать.

Comment: Более того, вы сами упомянули идую хранения чего-то вперемешку - добавления соли (salt). Для токена такой солью может быть, например, подсеть, версия браузера и любой хлам, который можно угадать, но не элементарно.  В купе с ограниченой жизнью токена, он, в идеале, устареет раньше, чем злоумышленник им воспользуется.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов
Но ведь в уроке он показывал, что токен генерируется один раз при регистрации! Или надо каждый раз при входе генерировать новый?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Но ведь в уроке он показывал, что токен генерируется один раз при регистрации! Или надо каждый раз при входе генерировать новый?

Comment: Не смотрел его, но осуждаю )

Comment: @VladimirGamalian то есть мне просто стоит генерировать токен при каждой новой авторизации, я правильно понимаю? И да, еще такой момент. Предположим, что пользователь переустановил себе ОС. Получается, что куки auth_token в браузере уже нет, но значение auth_token'а-то в БД лежит! Обнулять токен в БД я могу при каждом логауте, только вот если логаута не было, то что делать с токеном в БД? Ведь небезопасно его там оставлять.

Comment: Удаляйте токен из бд по истечении таймаута, например если юзер бездействует 30 минут. redis, к примеру, дает такую возможность из коробки (задать время жизни ключа/значения).

Comment: Использование токена дает и другие возможности, например можно вынести авторизационный сервер отдельно (если токен подписывать, то даже не придется связывать авторизационный сервер с сервером приложения).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Это правильное соображение, что токен хранить "как есть" нельзя

**Но хранить хэш пароля в куке ещё хуже.**

Хэшировать токен доступа очень даже стоит, и есть реализации этого, например, [в `devise_token_auth`](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb#L10). Хотя некоторым он кажется несколько *параноидальным*, в особенности смена токена на каждый запрос.

Но там это не приводит к катастрофическому замедлению страницы. Как? **Кэш.** Вместо постоянного пересчёта *bcrypt-хэшей* от одинаковых токенов система держит **в оперативной памяти** кэш последних 10000 обработанных токенов.

**Можно ли влезть в этот кэш?** Теоретически... **да**, если знать где искать (а если есть доступ к серверу, то догадаться недолго). С помощью GDB можно подсоедниться в работающему Ruby-процессу и с помощью рефлексии, которой в Ruby полно, добраться до нужного объекта.

Но если на сервере дыра, позволяющая это сделать, у вас куда более серьёзные проблемы.